# Amcharts Map, how to make default zoom to Asia continent

Tags: amcharts, ammap

How to make default zoom to Asia continent when page loads. in Amcharts map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`zoomLatitude`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapData#zoomLatitude), [`zoomLongitude`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapData#zoomLongitude) and [`zoomLevel`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapData#zoomLevel) in your map `dataProvider` to the default position and zoom level you want the map to be on load.

Example below:

```js
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "continentsLow",
    "zoomLatitude": 47.8936,
    "zoomLongitude": 115.6176,
    "zoomLevel": 2,
    "getAreasFromMap": true,
    "areas": [{
      "id": "asia",
      "showAsSelected": true
    }]
  },
  "areasSettings": {
    "autoZoom": false,
    "selectedColor": "#CC0000"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/continentsLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width:100%; height: 250px"></div>
```